# Use a SELECT to Print a Bunch of INSERT INTOs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a bunch of records I want to move to another database and I just want to create a bunch of inserts that I can copy and paste. I've seen someone do this before but I can't figure it out. I'm not getting the escapes right.

It's something like this where 'Code', 'Description' and 'Absent' are the columns I want from the table.

```
 SELECT 'INSERT INTO AttendanceCodes
          (Code, Description, Absent) 
         VALUES 
          (' + Code + ',' + Description  + ',' + Absent')'
  FROM AttendanceCodes
```

The end result should be a slew of INSERTS with the correct values like this:

```
 INSERT INTO AttendanceCodes 
   (Code, Description, Absent) 
 VALUES 
   ('A','Unverified Absence','UA')
```

Comment: Final Solution all tidied up:
SELECT 'INSERT INTO AttendanceCodes (Code, Description, Absent) VALUES (''' + Code + ''',''' + Description  + ''',''' + Absent + ''')' 
  FROM AttendanceCodes

Comment: Why are you copying records one at a time? Very poor practice.

Comment: I suspect he's creating a script to fill in a static table as part of a db creation process--perfectly good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
SELECT 'INSERT INTO AttendanceCodes (Code, Description, Absent) VALUES (''' + Code + ''',''' + Description  + ''',''' + Absent''')' 
  FROM AttendanceCodes
```

Comment: i would add a `N` before each value to make sure unicode text ( *if present* ) gets copied correctly in the new database...

Comment: Perfect. My only question is, how did you respond so fast? Geesh!

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
 SELECT 
    'INSERT INTO AttendanceCodes (Code, Description, Absent) VALUES (' 
        + ISNULL(''''+CONVERT(varchar(8000),Code)+'''','null')
        + ',' 
        + ISNULL(''''+CONVERT(varchar(8000),Description)+'''','null')
        + ',' 
        + ISNULL(''''+CONVERT(varchar(8000),Absent)+'''','null')
        +')'
    FROM AttendanceCodes
```

This will handle NULLs.  I'm not sure of your columns data types, but you can only concatenate strings, so I forced everything to varchar(8000), you can modify this as necessary.

Comment: This is definitely a more thorough solution but it's more than what I need. Thanks!

Comment: I rarely concatenate a string without considering NULLS and data type, get in the habit and you'll have fewer data type conversion errors and null strings that should contain a value to debug.

Answer (score 0):

For a generic stored procedure that takes a table name (and some other options) and generates insert statements for current data in that table, check out this handy 
[link](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/code/generate_inserts.txt).

It creates a procedure called sp_generate_inserts.  You pass this procedure the table name, and it will generate all the insert statements to recreate the data.